# Angular set @inputs and access @outputs from unrelated component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dynamic table component (DataTableComponent) that takes in various @inputs and contains an @output:

```html
<app-data-table (buttonClickedEvent)="buttonClickedEvent($event)" [data]="testTableSetup.data" [mutatorArray]="testTableSetup.mutatorArray" [hiddenProps]="testTableSetup.hiddenProps" [showSelectColumn]="testTableSetup.showSelectColumn" [showEditColumn]="testTableSetup.showEditColumn"
[actionButtons]="testTableSetup.actionButtons">
</app-data-table>
```

I also have a dynamic dialog component that can take in an optional parameter so I can pass in other components to be displayed within:

```js
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    let dialogConfigModel: DialogConfigModel = {
      dynamicFormModel: [],
      additionalComp: DataTableComponent,
      click_ButtonText: "Save",
      close_ButtonText: "Close",
      dialogTitle: "SOME TITLE"
    };
    dialogConfig.data = dialogConfigModel;

    const dialogRef = this._dialog.open(DynamicDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe(results => {
        // Stuff Here.
      });
  }
```

The component does appear in my dialog as expected, but it has no data obviously.

How can I access my DataTableComponent @inputs and @output from within this openDialog() method? I need to be able to set the @inputs data and get when the @output method is fired. Is this not possible? Or is there a better way to accomplish this? I have checked out injectors, but I could not get the implementation to work.

Comment: Try using RxJs Subject check this blog out http://coding-karma.com/2018/05/06/angular-5-sharing-data-components-using-rxjs-subject/

Comment: @DanPatil This is a great tutorial but after setting everything up this._dataShareService.shareDataSubject
      .subscribe(receiveddata => {
        console.log(receiveddata);
      }) Does not fire. Nothing is written to the console and the data is not recieved.

Comment: Nevermind. I realized you use Subject instead of BehaviorSubject in your tutorial. Subject does not hold a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to communicate them via a Service:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service
as there's no direct relation between them, you can inject a service in both,
and trigger an observable from one,
to listen to the changes in the second ;)

Comment: This makes sense. I will give it a try. Is this kind of how the Angular Material mat-dialog functions under the hood?

Comment: Kind of, the `mat-dialog` receives the "input" data vía `open()` and provides an observable like `afterClosed` to return an "output" value. You can design your data-flow in many ways, just need to organize it in a coherent way with the Angular tools that you know (components, services, ngrx, input/outputs, etc)

Comment: Awesome. Everything is now working. I followed the tutorial above with a few changes bc of my angular version. I also have a subject that relays when a button is clicked from the child, back to the parent comp. This is perfect.